# Watir #when_present inconsistent timeout issue

Tags: rspec, automation, watir-webdriver

I'm doing some automation using Rspec and Watir-webdriver--currently I have two different methods that use a common snippet like this

```
# The snippet shown is meant to find a specific div, and when an element within it is present, then perform the click action
search_modal = @browser.div(:class, 'asset-search')
search_modal.when_present do
    search_modal.div(:class, 'quick-search').click
end
```

I ran it for one method, and it worked properly with no errors.  I ran it on my second method, and it would timeout after 30 seconds.  Fast forward to this morning, and this second method is now running through properly.  
Again, this is the same code being used in two different methods.  Is there some underlying issue with using #wait methods?  If these are known for being brittle or finicky, is there a better way to code this? 
 Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the wait methods? When the wait times out, do you see the element you expected? Two things you want to verify are (1) does it normally take close to 30 seconds for the element to appear as that would mean sometimes being over or under the time limit and (2) is the action for triggering the `search_modal` always working? As an example of the latter, I had some autocomplete controls where setting the text field had inconsistent results for opening the autocomplete list - ie the problem was with triggering the modal as opposed to waiting for the modal.

Comment: @JustinKo, I would say it's a bit of both.  On the screen when I watch it, it is going to the right place, but in the terminal times out after 30 seconds saying it couldn't find the right element--which is confusing when it actually gets there!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect part of your problem may be that you are creating a variable that is basically going to be static once created.  so it will either be a div object, which then passes the present test, or a null object that will timeout before becoming present.  (unless I'm very confused)

Try this and see if it works any better.

```
@browser.div(:class, 'asset-search').div(:class, 'quick-search').when_present.click
```

If that gives an error you might need to do it in two stages

```
@browser.div(:class, 'asset-search').wait_until_present
@browser.div(:class, 'asset-search').div(:class, 'quick-search').when_present.click
```

Alternatively if there is only a single instance of a div with the class quick-search (so you would not need to constrict the browser to looking for it inside the asset-search div) then you could do

```
@browser.div(:class, 'quick-search').when_present.click
```